# ApplicationInfo on Android in static method

Tags: android

Not that complicated of a question today:

Is there a way to get the ApplicationInfo in a static method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

To get to `ApplicationInfo` you need instance of `Context`, which you get via and instance of `Application` or `Activity`.

So, normally you'd do:

```
ApplicationInfo appIngo = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("your.app.package.name", GET_META_DATA)
```

where `this` is and instance of Context, either Activity, Service or Application.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit your your application class from Application

```
public class TestApplication extends Application
```

create private static instance variable inside this class

```
private static TestApplication instance = null;
```

instantiate it in onCreate method:

```
instance = this;
```

write access method

```
public static TestApplication getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

From any place you can call

```
TestApplication.getInstance().getApplicationInfo()
```

Same way you can get ApplicationContext.